# Can Optional Catch-all Segments routing be set with some restrictions in NextJs?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I need my routing of NextJs application to work with certain rules:

```
path/to/sectionA
path/to/sectionB
path/to/sectionC
path/to/sectionC/subA
path/to/sectionC/subB
path/to/sectionC/subB/dynamic1
path/to/sectionC/subB/dynamic2
path/to/sectionC/subB/dynamic3
path/to/sectionC/subB/dynamicX
```

Then Optional Catch-all Segments routing defined in my `[[...section]].ts` file seems a good option. But in my application these routes are strict, in the sense that for example `path/to/sectionB/whatever` can't be accepted and router should redirect to not found. Which is the best way to approach it?